# using a content delivery network for user uploaded images?

Tags: cdn, content-delivery-network

like their profile pictures and albums?

Comment: what platforms and languages are you using? Which CDN did you have in mind? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is being asked here?  Do you want to know if it's possible, or how to do it, or what?

Comment: The original title was 'can yo use a content delivery network for user uploaded images?', but two people then edited it to *remove* the first two words instead of *changing* to 'Can you'.

Comment: yes my question was if I can. I haven't looked into anything yet. But I want something to upload my users on my social network. I have about 100-300 users online at a time. I'm using php-mysql for the most part. I want a CDN where I can tell it what the name of the file is gonna be, or if thats not possible get it to ping a page back after upload so I can put the location for the user photo in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Here are examples on configuration for [Wordpress](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/wordpress-cdn-content-delivery-network-configuration.html) and [vbulletin](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/vbulletin-cdn-content-delivery-network-configuration.html). These articles also contain a good overview of the benefits of using an CDN, and how different content distribution methods work.

Of course configuration will depend on your own system, as well as the CDN you go with.